# Why has this blurry icon suddenly appeared on Kotlin-related tags?

Tags: discussion

This icon is now a part of the main [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) tag, as well as most other narrower tags, such as [kotlinx.coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx.coroutines), [rx-kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rx-kotlin), [kotlin-null-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-null-safety).

1. Why do Kotlin tags have an Android on them?
2. Why are they in such miserable quality?

[image: Kotlin tag]

Comment: FWIW, you might want to add the list of tags that this icon is appearing on.

Comment: 3. What is it? Something like a rainbow armadillo?

Comment: It's the Android robot dressed with a Superman-style cape in Kotlin colors and with the Kotlin badge on the chest. https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgKDbnsWyFhABGAEyCGnPt2JivLfK